# Bottom list in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

How can I show this type of list in a UIWebView, after that a button is pressed?
(list elements are: "Open in Safari", "Copy link", "Cancel")

[image: bottom list]

Comment: Do you mean, when someone presses a button that lives inside your webview (a button defined by html/css), how to show this UIActionSheet?

Comment: UIActionSheet https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of posts out there describing how to respond to javascript calls inside your objective-c / swift code:

http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

And the system UI you're interested in showing in response to that javascript action is a UIActionSheet:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html